# Decoding using string as a code in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, loops

What am I trying to do is to have a program which compresses strings like AAABBBBCAAAaaDD -> A3B4CA3a2D2 and then decompresses it. First function already works but the second one seems to have problem to see first element of string:

```
taba = list(string)
decompressed = ''

for i in range(2, len(taba)):
    k = 0
    if str(taba[i]).isnumeric():
        while k < int(taba[i]):
            decompressed += taba[i-1]
            k += 1
```

With input = AAABBBBCAAAaaDD, string = A3B4CA3a2D2 and with this string decompressed returns BBBBCAAAaaDD. What can cause the loop to not include taba[2-1]?

Comment: if you have control over `string` add a `1` after your `C`. It will make things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's because you're indexing from 2 instead of 0? What was the reasoning behind that? What were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: *facepalms* yeah, I just didn't realised a thing. I'm a programming noob so it's a cause of my misconception

Comment: Well, what did you think it did? This could be a useful learning moment

Answer (score 0):

Well, your for loop clearly leaves out the first two letters.

```
for i in range(2, len(taba)):
```

You'd need to start looping from 0.